# Cannot edit settings on exisitng approved Classic API application

Tags: paypal

I have recently taken over development of a web application which communicates with paypal to do Adaptive Payments using the paypal Classic API.

I was debugging an issue I found in which paypal disallows all transactions which include a chain-payment.

I logged into developer.paypal.com and navigated through the "Create and Manage Classic API Apps" link to find the old apps management interface.

I see my application in the list, and in the application settings the Chain Payments checkbox is unselected. I guess that is the reason that the transactions which include a chain payment are not allowed to be completed.

My problem is that I cannot edit any of the settings for the application. All of the fields in the form are set to readonly, and if I force the form to submit I get message "This application is not in an editable state".

The app was only submitted and approved in February 2015, so its not like it is that old. Is there a limitation that the application cannot be changed after it is approved? How can I enable chain payment permissions on this existing app?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to update/edit, if your application is approved. You will need to submit a new app at [www.paypal-apps.com](https://www.paypal-apps.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Just as a small follow up question, my supervisor told me the previous developer had Chain payments working fine on the app before he left. (In the current approval configuration). Is it possible that paypal used to allow chain payments on all apps, but recently changed it so that they now require explicit approval?

Comment: Chain Payments always needed approval.This is kinda advanced feature which the app review team will review and approve and I don't think this has changed recently.